# Modulus: Invariant Domain

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$.

Consider an operator:
$$M:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{K}:\quad \|M\|=1$$

Regard dense domains:
$$\overline{\mathcal{D}}=\mathcal{H}\quad\overline{\mathcal{E}}=\mathcal{K}$$

Then for modulus:
$$M\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{E}\quad M^*\mathcal{E}\subseteq\mathcal{D}\implies|M|\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{D}$$

How can I check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I finally disproved it...*

Given the Hilbert space $\mathcal{L}^2([0,1])$.

Denote for shorthand:
$$\eta\in\mathcal{L}^2([0,1]):\quad\eta(x):=e^{-x}$$

Consider multiplication:
$$M_\eta:\mathcal{L}^2([0,1])\to\mathcal{L}^2([0,1]):\quad\|M_\eta\|=\|\eta\|_{[0,1]}=1$$

By functional calculus:
$$M^*=M\geq0\implies |M|=M$$

Regard the domains:
$$\mathcal{D}:=\langle\mathcal{P}\cup\{\eta^{2k}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\rangle\quad\mathcal{E}:=\langle\mathcal{P}\cup\{\eta^{2k+1}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\rangle$$

Then for modulus:
$$M\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{E}\quad M^*\mathcal{E}\subseteq\mathcal{D}\quad|M|\mathcal{D}\nsubseteq\mathcal{D}$$

Hence counterexample!